# Xcode: changing SVN repo details

Tags: xcode, svn, repository

This is about outdated repo details inside XCode. The case is:

1. I'm reusing a supporting library from an old project in a new one.
2. I used "Add files to X project..." functionality to copy them to the new place.
3. "Automagically" the files were copied with a reference to an old SVN repo, that don't exit anymore.

So... Now I have a project with 2 repos visible, incl. one inactive. I can't commit changes to copied files, as the old repo is still linked.
Two question here:

1. Is there a way to edit old repo data?
2. Is there a way to move the copied files to the new repo, where the rest of the project is?

Ultimately I need to commit both parts ;)
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. So resolving this issues required several steps to be performed. Not sure **if all were required**, but the eventually I got it right.

1. Commit all changes you can (in my case all but the folder that was linked with the old repo). Archive your projects.
2. Go to the root folder of your project and use `svn switch --relocate` command to merge repos. Details: [how to change svn settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127134/how-to-change-subversion-settings-in-xcode)
3. Remove the project from XCode (via Organizer) delete the entire project folder
4. Remove repos in the Organizer
5. Fetch whatever was committed in the SVN again. Do that and create a new project. If you see any missing files highlighted in red, like my folder that couldn't be committed, delete it.
6. Manually add the missing files / folder that to the project, from a local copy.
7. Now you can commit to the repo!

Tiresome, like most things in XCode... ;)