# XCode SVN commit doesn't show changed files after relocate

Tags: xcode, svn

The SVN repository I was using for XCode was relocated to another server and I was require to perform the relocate inside XCode. The command I used for relocating was:

```
svn relocate oldLocation newLocation
```

The command itself worked great. The problem I'm encountering is that now whenever I click on `Source Control` -> `Commit`, the GUI that appears doesn't show any of the modified files.

If I use the command line and use either `svn stat` and `svn commit`, I can perform the necessary functions. While the command line tools work, it does add a lot of time when trying to commit any modified files. Is there another setting within XCode that I need to change in order to allow myself to commit using the GUI?

Comment: Possible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12450450/3051458

Comment: I have performed the `svn relocate` on the command line. The post does mention using the deprecated `svn switch --relocate`, but that's used prior to 1.7. I refreshed the status under the `Source Control` tab and no luck. I did not remove that project from organizer, since that has many previous builds and also data about any crashes from prior builds.